# Solrcloud replica down after modify heap size jvm memory

Tags: solr, lucene, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I had to increase the JVM-Memory to 10g from the default value 512m of solr.I changes the values directly in the files ‘solr/bin/solr.cmd‘ and ‘solr/bin/solr.in.cmd‘ and restarted the solr cloud.

All the replica showing statuses as Down mode. And Iam getting error message like status 404 when execute query on the collection.
Nothing is showing in log about the replicas down.

What are steps I need to perform to get the all replicas to Active mode?

Comment: Can you please provide more information about how many nodes you have, how much memory is available for each node, how many replicas, index size etc.

Comment: @Seasers I had to reindex the data. Can you suggest on memory distribution? I have 6GB of Data, 12 string fields. Available RAM is 16 GB, Disk Storage is SSD 1TB. Search should perform 12 strings fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand why you had to increase the JVM memory from 512 MB directly to 10 GB.
You should know that Solr and Lucene use MMapDirectory as default. This means that all indexes are not loaded in the JVM virtual memory but they are allocated in a dedicated space of memory. [This blog post can help you](https://dzone.com/articles/use-lucene%E2%80%99s-mmapdirectory)
Considering you have 16GB RAM available, as a first iteration, I'd allocate 4 GB to the JVM so that 12GB remains available for the operating system (and 6GB of index files). Then, by monitoring the system memory and the JVM memory, you can do better tuning.

That being said, I don't think the high JVM allocated memory is enough to break all Solr instances. Can you please verify that you updated only the JVM heap memory value? Can you also verify if the logs show some initialization failures?

There is still some missing information:

- How many nodes your SolrCloud is composed of?
- How many replicas? And what type of replica?

PS: Considering you are working on `solr.cmd` and `solr.in.cmd` I assume your server is Windows, the Linux version invokes the `solr.in.sh` script.

Comment: under one node I have added 8 collections and each collection's numshards=23, replicationfactor=2 on windows Server but the response is very very slow. I used docvalue index

Comment: You should be aware that if you increase the number of shards, you split the index into 23 parts so when you submit a query to Solr, your query is broadcasted to each shard, collected all results, and merged together to create the final query response. This is why your query is very very slow. I'd suggest you reduce the number of shards (only one shard may be enough)